# How to remove module definition from build without breaking my app?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have a SPA that uses RequireJS and has a module that defines different URLs to use depending on the environment in which the app is deployed.

I have modified my build command to exclude this environment config module so that I can leave the relevant config within that environment (instead of modifying the environment module before deploying to a new environment). Like so...

```
node r.js -o app-build.js paths.env=empty:
```

Here's an example of my environment.js module

```
define({
    reports: {
        base: 'http://reports.app.com'
    }
})
```

Here's an example of my require.config()

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        env: '../../scripts/environment'
    }
})
```

The following is an example of how I would consume the module....

```
define(["jquery", "env"], function ($, _env) {
    $.get( _env.reports.base + "/ReportName");
});
```

The issue I am having is now that `environment.js` is excluded, `_env` is `undefined`. 
Can anyone show me what I am missing?

Comment: Is '_env' supposed to be quoted in your function parameters? Not sure that can be the problem as I'm not sure that's valid JS in the first place.

Comment: @PaulGrime You're right. Let me edit that out of there (it's not in my problematic source code either).